# How to find HA interface mac address in Fortigate?

Tags: firewall, mac-address, fortigate

We have two Fortinet and HA them. In "primary" I can see the Mac address for all interfaces easily in Network -> Interfaces -> Edit Interface. but I can't find the Mac address for "secondary" interfaces.